# How to make same collection inner join equivalent in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection that looks like EAV (or some key/value):

```
{domain_id: 1, key: "A", value: 1}
{domain_id: 1, key: "B", value: 2}
{domain_id: 1, key: "C", value: 3}

{domain_id: 2, key: "A", value: 5}
{domain_id: 2, key: "B", value: 2}
{domain_id: 2, key: "C", value: 3}

{domain_id: 3, key: "C", value: 3}
```

I need to find all `domain_id` what have `key = "A" AND value = 1` and also have `key = "C" AND value = 3` (intersection, not OR condition) so supposed result will be:

```
{domain_id: 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group By `domain_id` and `$push` document in `data` field.
2. `$match` - Use `$and` for multiple comparisons, [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to match field value in array element.
3. `$project` - Select `domain_id`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$domain_id",
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "data": {
            $elemMatch: {
              "key": "A",
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "data": {
            $elemMatch: {
              "key": "C",
              "value": 3
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      domain_id: "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BoYwoCujKJE)

Comment: Thanks! i tested it - all works as expected!